# Is there a way I could make a try-try-catch block?

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

I am using Apache POI to try and read word files, but this should still be answerable even if you have worked with Apache POI. In the HWPF.extractor package there are two objects, the WordExtractor and the Word6Extractor, the text extractor for older Microsoft Word formats. I am trying to use a try catch statement to try the WordExtractor object. Then if that throws an error it should try the Word6Extractor before throwing an exception.

I have already tried this:

```
try{
    WordExtractor example = new WordExtractor(...);
} try{
    Word6Extractor example = new Word6Extractor(...);
} catch(Exception e)
{
    //code to alert user to bad file type
}
```

If there's anything else you need to know just tell me and I will try to provide it.

Comment: put it in the catch block?

Comment: Your code wouldn't work the way you describe even if it was legal, which it isn't, and whcuh you could have determined for yourself in 30 seconds. Don't just invent non-existent syntax. Write programs.

Comment: @EJP I wasn't inventing non-existent syntax I was asking a question on how to correctly perform what I wanted to do. There was no need to write your rather rude comment and believe it or not I am writing a program (one thats got almost 3000 lines of code none the less). I am just unused to using error handling.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only thing wrong with your code is the syntax! Although using exceptions for control flow is pretty messy, and commonly it's bad coding practice (or so I've been taught), I do believe this should do the trick:

```
try{
  WordExtractor example = new WordExtractor(...);
} catch (Exception e){

  // If there is an exception thrown, we run the next block of code
  try 
  {
    Word6Extractor example = new Word6Extractor(...);
  } catch(Exception e)
  {
    //code to alert user to bad file type
  }

}
```

Hope this clears it up!

Comment: Ya know I thought about doing this, but in my head it didn't seem like it would do what I wanted, but reading the code makes it look different and I realize this is exactly what I needed! Thank you! Also I agree with the control flow thing but I think this is probably the best way to do it in this case.